# multiple definition of template specialization when using different objects

Tags: c++, templates

When I use a specialized template in different object files, I get a "multiple definition" error when linking. The only solution I found involves using the "inline" function, but it just seems like some workaround. How do I solve that without using the "inline" keyword? If that's not possible, why?

Here is the example code:

```
paulo@aeris:~/teste/cpp/redef$ cat hello.h 
#ifndef TEMPLATE_H
#define TEMPLATE_H

#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Hello
{
public:
    void print_hello(T var);
};

template <class T>
void Hello<T>::print_hello(T var)
{
    std::cout << "Hello generic function " << var << "\n";
}

template <> //inline
void Hello<int>::print_hello(int var)
{
    std::cout << "Hello specialized function " << var << "\n";
}

#endif
```

---

```
paulo@aeris:~/teste/cpp/redef$ cat other.h 
#include <iostream>

void other_func();
```

---

```
paulo@aeris:~/teste/cpp/redef$ cat other.c 
#include "other.h"

#include "hello.h"

void other_func()
{
    Hello<char> hc;
    Hello<int> hi;

    hc.print_hello('a');
    hi.print_hello(1);
}
```

---

```
paulo@aeris:~/teste/cpp/redef$ cat main.c 
#include "hello.h"

#include "other.h"

int main()
{
    Hello<char> hc;
    Hello<int> hi;

    hc.print_hello('a');
    hi.print_hello(1);

    other_func();

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
paulo@aeris:~/teste/cpp/redef$ cat Makefile
all:
    g++ -c other.c -o other.o -Wall -Wextra
    g++ main.c other.o -o main -Wall -Wextra
```

---

Finally:

```
paulo@aeris:~/teste/cpp/redef$ make
g++ -c other.c -o other.o -Wall -Wextra
g++ main.c other.o -o main -Wall -Wextra
other.o: In function `Hello<int>::print_hello(int)':
other.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Hello<int>::print_hello(int)'
/tmp/cc0dZS9l.o:main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: ** [all] Erro 1
```

If I uncomment the "inline" inside hello.h, the code will compile and run, but that just seems like some kind of "workaround" to me: what if the specialized function is big and used many times? Will I get a big binary? Is there any other way to do this? If yes, how? If not, why?

I tried to look for answers, but all I got was "use inline" without any further explanation.

Thanks

Comment: put actual specialized implementation into .cpp rather then header file

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Intuitively, when you fully specialize something, it doesn't depend on a template parameter any more -- so unless you make the specialization inline, you need to put it in a .cpp file instead of a .h or you end up violating the one definition rule as David says. Note that when you partially specialize templates, the partial specializations do still depend on one or more template parameters, so they still go in a .h file.

Comment: Hmmm I am still a bit confused about how it breaks the ODR. Because you only define the fully specialized template once. You may be creating the object multiple times in different object files (ie. in this case it is instantiated in other.c and main.c) but the original object itself is defined only in one file - in this case `hello.h`.

Comment: @JustinLiang: The header is included in two separate .c files - that has the same effect as if you'd written its contents (including the full specialization) directly into the files in which it's included at the relevant places. The One Definition Rule (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) says (among other things): "In the entire program, an object or non-inline function cannot have more than one definition". In this case, the full specialization of the function template is in essence just like a normal function, so unless it's inline it can't have more than one definition.

Comment: Hmmm, I noticed that when we don't have a templated specialization this error will not appear. Let's say we had two different functions that were defined in the header file, outside of the class, they will still work without the inline? For example: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bRaiNC7M. I took that class and included it in two files. Wouldn't this have" the same effect as if you'd written the contents" directly into the two files and thus there will be a multiple definition error?

Comment: @Justin Liang, your class based header code will still violate the ODR if included in multiple files, unless the function definitions are inside the body of the class.

Comment: So, if my static member definition is preceded by `template <typename T>` then it may go into a header, and if it's `template<>` then it may not?

Answer (score 62):

The keyword `inline` is more about telling the compiler that the symbol will be present in more than one object file without violating the One Definition Rule than about actual inlining, which the compiler can decide to do or not to do.

The problem you are seeing is that without the inline, the function will be compiled in all translation units that include the header, violating the ODR. Adding `inline` there is the right way to go. Otherwise, you can forward declare the specialization and provide it in a single translation unit, as you would do with any other function.

Answer (score 26):

You've explicitly instantiated a template in your header (`void Hello<T>::print_hello(T var)`).  This will create multiple definitions.  You can solve it in two ways:

1) Make your instantiation inline.

2) Declare the instantiation in a header and then implement it in a cpp.

Comment: Actually there is a 3rd way which is to put those in a no name namespace... which is similar to having static in C.

Comment: That's not valid here.  A template specialization needs to be in the same namespace as the original template.

Comment: Also, unnamed namespaces in headers are themselves sources of One Definition Rule violations, and thus recommended against by the CppCoreGuidelines: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rs-unnamed

Answer (score 1):

Here is some [piece](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.expl.spec#12) of C++11 standard related to this issue:

> An explicit specialization of a function template is inline only if it
>   is declared with the inline specifier or defined as deleted, and
>   independently of whether its function template is inline. [ Example:
>
> template void f(T) { /* ... */ } template inline T
>   g(T) { /* ... */ }
>
> template<> inline void f<>(int) { /* ... */ }   // OK: inline
>   template<> int g<>(int) { /* ... */ }           // OK: not inline  —
>   end example ]

So if you make some explicit(aka full) specializations of templates in `*.h` file, then you will still need `inline` to help you get rid of the violation of **ODR**.