# how to select a code path for different type in a member template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class which returns the specific device based on runtime.

```
struct ComponentDc;
struct ComponentIc;

typedef Device<ComponentDc> DevComponentDc;
typedef Device<ComponentIc> DevComponentIc;

template<class Component>
class Device{
 Device<Component>* getDevice() { return this; }
 void exec() { }
};
```

In `exec()`, I'd like to print "Hello" if the component type is `ComponentDc` and world if it is `ComponentIc`. Also, these are the only two types with which Device can be created.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two classic possibilities.

First, use two global function overloads, one for `ComponentDc`, one for `ComponentIc`:

```
void globalExec(ComponentDc) { std::cout << "Hello"; }
void globalExec(ComponentIc) { std::cout << "World"; }

void Device<Component>::exec() { globalExec(Component); }
```

Second, use traits-class: pure template class with no fields and with different typedefs and only static functions as methods. This class has own specializations for different possible argument types.

```
template<Component> class DeviceTraits {};

template<> class DeviceTraits<ComponentDc> { 
    static std::string getMessage() { return "Hello"; }
};

template<> class DeviceTraits<ComponentIc> { 
    static std::string getMessage() { return "World"; }
};

void Device<Component>::exec() { 
    std::cout << DeviceTraits<Component>::getMessage(); 
}
```

The advantage of using traits classes is that you don't have to spoil your global namespace with several functions.

About partially specializing the `Device` class itself - it is not always possible, and it is considered more convenient to move any template-argument-specific code into traits class.

This is the classic approach used in STL. Alternatively, you can use `boost::enable_if` or `std::enable_if` (for the latest compilers).

Comment: I'm afraid global functions is not an option. I simplified my question here, so it has to be a member. Can you elaborate on traits classes ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could instantiate template explicitly:

```
template<> class Device<ComponentDc> {
    ...
    void exec() { cout << "Hello"; }
};
```

The same goes for `Device<ComponentIc>`.

Also, if you want to restrict template parameters to a specific set, you should think of inheritance or composition instead of templates.

Comment: How would this be called though ?

Comment: Just like before, `DevComponentDc dc; dc.exec();` The compiler would make specific code depending on template parameter implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use boost::enable_if

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html

```
void Device<Component>::exec(boost::enable_if< boost::is_same<Component,ComponentDc> >* enabler = 0)
{
}

void Device<Component>::exec(boost::enable_if< boost::is_same<Component,ComponentIc> >* enabler = 0)
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course, you are right ! I always try it out and then get bitten by that.

Answer (score 0):

Use for instance template specialization: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html

Here to use it for the specific method:
[Template specialization of a single method from a templated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723537/template-specialization-of-a-single-method-from-a-templated-class)