# Template specialization of a single method from templated class with multiple template parameters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, specialization

I'm basically trying to do what was discussed in [Template specialization of a single method from a templated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723537/template-specialization-of-a-single-method-from-a-templated-class) except that my TClass has multiple template Parameters like this:

```
template < class KEY, class TYPE >
class TClass
{
public:
    :
    void doSomething(KEY * v);
    :
};

template < class KEY, class TYPE >
void TClass<KEY, TYPE>::doSomething(KEY * v) 
{
    // do something
}
```

This works so far, but how do I define a specialized implementation for one template Parameter? I tried adding this:

```
template < class TYPE >
void TClass<int, TYPE>::doSomething(int * v)
{
    // do something if KEY is int
}
```

but the Compiler complains about "unable to match function Definition to an existing declaration" (VC2010) for that method/function.

As a sidenote: If I specialize both template Parameters at the same time, it works:

```
template < >
void TClass<int, char>::doSomething(int * v)
{
    // do something if KEY is int and TYPE is char
}
```

but that's not what I want to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Btw, the error messages from VS2015 can be wildly unhelpful.  C3860: wrong template parameter order, and C2995: template already defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specialize the entire class before you define a method through a partial specialization:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class TClass;

template <typename T>
class TClass<int, T>
{
    void doSomething(int* v);
};

template <typename T>
void TClass<int, T>::doSomething(int* v)
{
    // ...
}
```

***[Live demo](http://ideone.com/tWK25Z#view_edit_box)***

Answer (score 1):

You can fully specialize class method but as far as I remember you can't partially specialize it.

You can try partial specialization for the whole class but this will probably involve a lot of duplication.

Comment: Both of your answers baasically state the same. I marked 0x499602D2's answer because it is more elaborate.