# C++ specialize template class function without duplicating code

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, partial-specialization

I want to write 5 different classes, each of which has many member functions which are exactly the same, except of one, which is special for each class. Can I write this avoiding code duplication?

Regards,
Aleksejs

Below is a very shortened version of my code, which throws the error:

```
template_test.cpp:15:35: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class impl_prototype<cl, 1>
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <int cl, int dim>
class impl_prototype {
public:
  impl_prototype() {}

  int f(int x) { return cl + 2 * g(x); }
  int g(int x) { return cl + 1 * x;}

};

template <int cl>
int impl_prototype<cl, 1>::g(int x) { return cl + 3 * x; }

int main ()
{
  impl_prototype<0, 0> test_0;
  impl_prototype<0, 1> test_1;


  cout << test_0.f(5) << " " << test_0.g(5) << std::endl;
  cout << test_1.f(5) << " " << test_1.g(5) << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can they have a common base class ?

Comment: How about inheritance and virtual functions?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg inheritance + partial specialization of a helper is more idiomatic, there is no `virtual` in sight in the OP's code.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182729/specializing-single-method-in-a-big-template-class/21183551#21183551)

Answer (score 3):

Member functions of class templates can be explicitly specialized but not partially specialized.

Just make a helper function object that you can partially specialize:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int cl, int dim>
struct g_impl
{
  int operator()(int x) { return cl + 1 * x;}    
};

template<int cl>
struct g_impl<cl, 1>
{
  int operator()(int x) { return cl + 3 * x; }    
};
```

and then call that helper (the tempoary function object will optimized away):

```
template <int cl, int dim>
class impl_prototype 
{
public:
  impl_prototype() {}

  int f(int x) { return cl + 2 * g(x); }
  int g(int x) { return g_impl<cl, dim>()(x); }
};

int main ()
{
  impl_prototype<0, 0> test_0;
  impl_prototype<0, 1> test_1;


  cout << test_0.f(5) << " " << test_0.g(5) << std::endl;
  cout << test_1.f(5) << " " << test_1.g(5) << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e59255e599be1072)

Comment: As an alternative to inheritance, we may forward to the helper: `int g(int x) { return g_impl<cl, dim>().g(x); }`.

Comment: @Jarod42 made a function object that can be partially specialized and called from `g()`. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Walter just made it a function object that is partially specialized.

Comment: @Walter: You may give extra info to the helper class method if needed.

Answer (score 3):

An other method is Tag dispatching, something like:

```
template <int cl, int dim>
class impl_prototype
{
    int g(int x, std::integral_constant<int, 1>) { return cl + 3 * x; }

    template <int I>
    int g(int x, std::integral_constant<int, I>) { return cl + 1 * x; }

public:
    int f(int x) { return cl + 2 * g(x); }
    int g(int x) { return g(x, std::integral_constant<int, dim>());}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

1. use inheritance, where you specialise the base class template and add the multitude of other identical member functions only with the derived class templates.
2. declare a helper class (function object) that is partially specialised and called from `impl_prototype<>::g()`. This is very similar to 1., but avoids inheritance (for an example, see the answer by TemplateRex);
3. use SFINAE to "specialise" the member function:

   ```
   template<int cl, int dim>
   class impl_prototype
   {
     template<bool dim_equals_one> typename std::enable_if<!dim_equals_one,int>::type
     _g(const int x) const { return cl+1*x; }
     template<bool dim_equals_one> typename std::enable_if< dim_equals_one,int>::type
     _g(const int x) const { return cl+3*x; }
   public:
     int f(const int x) const { return cl+2*g(x); }
     int g(const int x) const { return _g<dim==1>(x); }    
   };
   ```

I often use this last approach as it avoids all the issues of inheritance (in particular in the case of non-trivial constructors) and any helper objects outside the class.

In your particular example, a much simpler possibility is

```
template<int cl, int dim>
class impl_prototype
{
public:
  int f(const int x) const { return cl + 2 * g(x); }
  int g(const int x) const { return cl + (dim==1? 3*x : x); }   
};
```