# Add operator[] for vector when Type is unique_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

Suppose that we have the vector class below which has been shortened to minimum to showcase the question.

```
template <typename T>
class VectorT : private std::vector<T>
{
  using vec = std::vector<T>;
public:
  using vec::operator[];
  using vec::push_back;
  using vec::at;
  using vec::emplace_back;

  // not sure if this is the beast way to check if my T is really a unique_ptr
  template<typename Q = T>
  typename Q::element_type* operator[](const size_t _Pos) const { return at(_Pos).get(); }
};
```

Is there any way to check if T is a unique_ptr and if yes to add an operator[] to return the unique_ptr::element_type*. At the same time though the normal operator[] should also work.

```
VectorT<std::unique_ptr<int>> uptr_v; 
uptr_v.emplace_back(make_unique<int>(1));
//int* p1 = uptr_v[0]; // works fine if using vec::operator[]; is commented out
                       // then of course it wont work for the normal case
//std::cout << *p1;

VectorT<int*> v;
v.emplace_back(uptr_v[0].get());
int *p2 = v[0];
std::cout << *p2;
```

Any way to achieve something like that ?

**Edited**:

The reason I am asking for this is cause I can have say my container

```
class MyVec: public VectorT<std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>>
```

but I can also have a

```
class MyVecView: public VectorT<SomeClass*>
```

Both classes will pretty much have identical functions. So I am trying to avoid duplication by doing something like

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(VectorT<T>& vec)
{
    SomeClass* tmp = nullptr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        tmp = vec[i]; // this has to work though
        ....
    }
}
```

Then of course I can

```
MyVec::doSomething(){doSomething(*this);}
MyVecView::doSomething(){doSomething(*this);}
```

which of course means that the `operator[]` has to work for both cases

Comment: `int *p1 = uptr_v[0].get();` perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template specialization of a single method from a templated class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723537/template-specialization-of-a-single-method-from-a-templated-class)

Comment: @MatsPetersson edited my answer explaining my end goal and why this is not really a solution

Comment: @slawekwin I just want to be able to have operator[] overloead. The SFINAE part is working fine but something is not playing well with `using operator[]` and the one I wrote. There is something that I am missing and I dont think that the specialization will help in this case.

Comment: Just a caveat: be _very_ careful when deriving from standard containers. See the [various](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922248/is-there-any-real-risk-to-deriving-from-the-c-stl-containers) … [SO posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate) … [about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector).

Comment: @mindriot You should have noticed the private part in inheritance so all the posts you quoted actually don't apply at all.... There are 2 ways to do what I wanted. One is private inheritance which is pretty much "implemented in terms of" as Scott Meyers says. The other way would be composition. So there are no caveats here... Even if I went for composition I would have a `inline reference operator[](size_type _Off) const { return container[_Off]; }`. So I would be in the exact same situation I think.

Comment: Why not `auto tmp = v[i];` and then `*tmp` where required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<typename T> struct unique_ptr_type { };
template<typename T> struct unique_ptr_type<std::unique_ptr<T>> { using type = T; };

namespace detail {
    template<typename T> std::false_type is_unique_ptr(T const&);
    template<typename T> std::true_type is_unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<T> const&);
}
template<typename T>
using is_unique_ptr = decltype(detail::is_unique_ptr(std::declval<T>()));

template<typename T>
class VectorT : std::vector<T> {
    using vec = std::vector<T>;

public:
    using vec::at;
    using vec::emplace_back;
    using vec::push_back;

    template<typename Q = T,
             typename std::enable_if<!is_unique_ptr<Q>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    Q& operator [](std::size_t pos) { return vec::operator[](pos); }
    template<typename Q = T,
             typename std::enable_if<!is_unique_ptr<Q>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    Q const& operator [](std::size_t pos) const { return vec::operator[](pos); }

    template<typename Q = T,
             typename U = typename unique_ptr_type<Q>::type>
    U* operator [](std::size_t pos) { return vec::operator[](pos).get(); }
    template<typename Q = T,
             typename U = typename unique_ptr_type<Q>::type>
    U const* operator [](std::size_t pos) const { return vec::operator[](pos).get(); }
};
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/664b4b628fd890e9)</kbd>

SFINAE is used to only enable the custom `operator[]` if `T` is `std::unique_ptr<T>`, and to only enable `std::vector<T>::operator[]` otherwise.

Comment: I am selecting this as the right answer since it was closer to what I asked. Nonetheless there are more answers that are correct

Answer (score 1):

The goal here is to have only one `operator[]`.  Techniques with more than one `operator[]` violate DRY (don't repeat yourself), and it is hard to avoid having a template method whose body would not compile if instantiated (which, under a strict reading of the standard, could result in your code being ill-formed).

So what I'd do is model the "turn something into a pointer" like this:

```
namespace details {
  template<class T>
  struct plain_ptr_t;

  //specialzation for T*
  template<class T>
  struct plain_ptr_t<T*> {
    T* operator()(T* t)const{return t;}
  };

  //specialzation for std::unique_ptr
  template<class T, class D>
  struct plain_ptr_t<std::unique_ptr<T,D>> {
    T* operator()(std::unique_ptr<T>const& t)const{return t.get();}
  };

  //specialzation for std::shared_ptr
  template<class T>
  struct plain_ptr_t<std::shared_ptr<T>> {
    T* operator()(std::shared_ptr<T>const& t)const{return t.get();}
  };
}

struct plain_ptr {
  template<class T>
  typename std::result_of< details::plain_ptr_t<T>( T const& ) >::type
  operator()( T const& t ) const {
    return details::plain_ptr_t<T>{}( t );
  }
};
```

now `plain_ptr` is a functor that maps smart pointers to plain pointers, and pointers to pointers.

It rejects things that aren't pointers.  You could change it to just pass them through if you like, but it takes a bit of care.

We then use them to improve your `operator[]`:

```
typename std::result_of< plain_ptr(typename vec::value_type const&)>::type
operator[](size_t pos) const {
  return plain_ptr{}(at(pos));
}
```

notice that it is no longer a `template`.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7eb00ec7d9ebc8be).

Comment: Interesting approach and I also dont like violating DRY, even though I dont think that the SFINAE approach violates it. However I was not able to make this work and I am not sure what is wrong. There is a typename missing which I added in the live example https://ideone.com/EQq4wd I would appreciate some help if possible.

Comment: @xerion Mostly there was a `::type` missing in `plain_ptr::operator()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on plain pointers you could write something like

```
template<class T> auto plain_ptr(T* p) { return p; }
template<class T> auto plain_ptr(std::unique_ptr<T>& p) { return p.get(); }
```

and then do

```
tmp = plain_ptr(vec[i]); // tmp will be SomeClass*
```

or you could have tmp local:

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(VectorT<T>& vec)
{

    static_assert(std::is_same<T, SomeClass*>::value || 
      std::is_same<T, std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>>::value, 
      "doSomething expects vectors containing SomeClass!");

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto tmp = vec[i]; 
        // ... (*tmp).foo or tmp->foo ...
    }
    // or perhaps even
    for(auto&& tmp : vec)
    {
        // ... again (*tmp).foo or tmp->foo ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Sometimes simple is better. I could easily keep my vectorT class as is and use this without much hassle at all. Thanks