# Partial specialized template class (for container class type) is not called

Tags: c++, templates, partial, specialization

I am still working on this problem I posted some hours before:
[[How to overload/specialize template class function to handle arithmetic types and a container-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560473/how-to-overload-specialize-template-class-function-to-handle-arithmetic-types-an][1])
I tried to implement this solution. It compiles but the object is created with the DerivedClass-Constructor instead of the partial specialized template class DerivedClass< Eigen::ArrayBase >
Do you have an Idea where I made a (or some) misstakes?

```
template <typename T> class BaseClass
{
protected:
  T mem;

public:
  BaseClass(T arg) : mem(arg){};
};

template <typename T> class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<T>
{
public:
  DerivedClass(T arg): BaseClass<T>(arg){};
};

template <typename T>
class DerivedClass<Eigen::ArrayBase<T> >
    : public DerivedClass<Eigen::ArrayBase<T> >
{
public: 
  DerivedClass(Eigen::ArrayBase<T> arg):BaseClass<Eigen::ArrayBase<T> >(arg){};
};

int main
{
...
  Eigen::Array3d arg = Array3d::Random(3);
  DerivedClass<Eigen::Array3d> o(arg);
....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<template<class...>class Z>
struct template_instance_test {
  static std::false_type test(...);
  template<class...Ts>
  static std::true_type test( Z<Ts...> const* );
  template<class X>
  using tester = decltype(test( std::declval<X*>() ) );
};
template<template<class...>class Z, class T>
using is_derived_from_template = typename template_instance_test<Z>::template tester<T>;
```

we can now ask if something is an instance of a particular template, or derived from an instance of a particular template.

```
template<class X>
struct Base {};
template<class X>
struct Derived:Base<X> {};

template<class T>
struct Storage {
  T data;
};
template<class T, class=void>
struct Instance:Storage<T> {
  enum {is_special = false};
};
template<class T>
struct Instance<T, std::enable_if_t< is_derived_from_template<Base, T>{} > >:
  Storage<T> {
  enum { is_special = true };
};

int main() {
    Instance<int> i; (void)i;
    static_assert(!Instance<int>::is_special);
    Instance<Derived<int>> j; (void)j;
    static_assert(is_derived_from_template<Base, Base<int>>{});
    static_assert(is_derived_from_template<Base, Derived<int>>{});
    static_assert(Instance<Derived<int>>::is_special);
}
```

and we are done.  [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8486b2e51b03423).

Answer (score 1):

Your code should works if `Eigen::Array3d` is an alias (through `using` or `typedef`) of `Eigen::ArrayBase<T>` for some `T`.

But I suppose that `Eigen::Array3d` inherit from `Eigen::ArrayBase<T>`. So isn't a ``Eigen::ArrayBase`, so doesn't matches the partial specialization, so matches the main template.

If you want a specialization that intercept all classes derived from `Eigen::ArrayBase`, a possible solution is add an additional template parameter with a default value and activate the specialization only it `T` derive from some `Eigen::ArrayBase`.

Something as follows (caution: code not tested)

```
constexpr std::false_type isArray (...);

template <typename T>
constexpr std::true_type isArray (Eigen::ArrayBase<T> const *);

template <typename T, typename = std::true_type>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<T>
 {
   public:
      DerivedClass(T arg): BaseClass<T>(arg){}; 
 };

template <typename T>
class DerivedClass<T, decltype(isArray(std::declval<T*>())>
   : public DerivedClass<T>
 {
   public: 
      DerivedClass (T arg) : BaseClass<T>(arg){};
 };
```

Comment: Mh, okay. My aim is to be able to calculate on all derived classes of Eigen::ArrayBase<T> in this partial specialized template.
Is there a approach to solve this?

Comment: @teflon - I suppose it's possible but Isn't clear to me how `Array3d` and `ArrayBase<T>` are related (something as `Array3d : ArrayBase<Array3d>` ?) and what do you need to know in the partial specialization (the template parameter `T` of `ArrayBase`?)

Comment: @teflon - I've improved the answer adding an example that show how to specialize a class for classes derived from `ArrayBase` (but caution: I don't have an `Eigen` platform so I can't compile to verify it).

Comment: Yes, ArrayBase is the BaseClass of Array<> and Array3d is a typedef of Array<>
I tried to implement the ArrayBase Example from this site:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html

Comment: While academic, `std::false_type isArray (...);` called with a non-pod type is very underspecified by the standard.  I'd use pointers instead of values, which solves that issue.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - Everyday I learn something new about C++; i don't know if it's a good thing. Anyway, thanks as usual.